# PHP boolean TRUE / FALSE?

Tags: php, boolean

I can't figure this out.

If I type:

```
function myfunction(){
    ......
    if ...
        return TRUE;
    if ...
        return FALSE;
}
```

Why can't I use it like this:

```
$result = myfunction();
if ($result == TRUE)
...
if ($result == FALSE)
...
```

Or do I have to use:

```
$result = myfunction();
if ($result == 1)
...
if ($result == 0)
...
```

Or this:

```
$result = myfunction();
if ($result)
...
if (!$result)
...
```

Comment: Small remark: code that reads like this: `if … return true; else return false;` should **always** be rewritten to `return … === true;` or, in a type-safe language, simply to `return …;`. The `if` simply makes no sense here, since the condition we are testing already corresponds to the return value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but you *can* use any of the examples you provided, with the following caveats:

If you say `if (a == TRUE)` (or, since the comparison to `true` is redundant, simply `if (a)`), you must understand that PHP will evaluate several things as true: 1, 2, 987, "hello", etc.; They are all "truey" values. This is rarely an issue, but you should understand it.

However, if the function can return more than `true` or `false`, you may be interested in using `===`. `===` does compare the type of the variables:  `"a" == true` is `true`, but `"a" === true` is false.

Answer (score 6):

If you dont need to use the result variable $result furthermore, I would do the following shortest version:

```
if (myfunction()) {
    // something when true
} else {
    // something else when false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do like this

```
$result = myfunction();
if ($result === TRUE)
...
if ($result === FALSE)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if($result == TRUE)` but that's an overkill as `if($result)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($variable) 
//something when truw
else 
//something else when false
```

Remember that the value -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number. FALSE would be 0 obv...

Answer (score -1):

Double check you have gettype($result) == bool and NOT string.